# Can someone explain why nothing happens when I press the enter key?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain to why nothing happens when I press enter when I am in the 
the textbox?

```
<script>
function buttonCode(){
  alert("Button code executed.") }

var input = document.getElementById("userinput");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13){
event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById("button1").click();
    }
  });
</script>


<body>
  <input id="userinput" type ="text">
  <button id="button1"
          onclick = "buttonCode()"
          >
    Button
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you **expect** to happen?

Comment: @Quentin: The edit removed/solved the problem.  His code simply isn't finding the element because it executes before the element exists, which isn't an issue in SO code snippets by design.

Comment: Hmm looks like T.J. Crowder closed this as the same thing as I did and then reopened it. Pretty sure this is the issue though. @Vic4561 let us know if using a ready event or moving the script to the bottom of your html doesn't fix

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that function has a closing `}` so it wouldnt have wrapped the listener setup

Comment: @PatrickEvans - Ah, thanks. Vic - ***Please*** don't use that bracing style. Someone seems to be teaching it to people, I can't imagine why, but it's ***very*** hard to read and hard to edit (think how much work you have to do to move lines around in the block).

Comment: By far the easiest way to get this to do what you want, assuming what you want is a form submission, is to remove all of the code and put the `input` and `button` in a `form`. Then, since there's only one `input`, pressing Enter in it will trigger a form submission.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<body>
  <input id="userinput" type ="text">
  <button id="button1" onclick = "buttonCode()" >
    Button
  </button>

  <script>

function buttonCode(){
  alert("Button code executed.") }

var input = document.getElementById("userinput");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13){
event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById("button1").click();
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Try this ***need to write script after html elements***